# MySQL - Most performant way to prune a lot of orphaned rows

Tags: mysql, query-performance, database-administration, orphaned-objects

Refactoring some old code we've discovered that objects of class X are being created far too often and ~80% of them are being left without a reference.

I have ~10 tables that reference rows in the table of class X. I can easily identify the number of orphaned rows. The table has around 7 million rows and only around 1.5 million represent legitimately referenced objects.

After fixing the code causing this issue I need to delete all of these orphaned rows in a moderately performant way.

With my limited DB admin experience the only way I know to do this is to select all the legitimate IDs of 'X-type' objects and then do something like: `DELETE FROM x WHERE id NOT IN (valid_references)`. That's something like 10 trillion comparisons, there has to be a better way.

Comment: For the future, you might look at cascade on delete

Comment: @strawberry I'm aware of that method, but thanks for the heads up. These rows aren't orphaned due to deleted parents (at least most of them). They're orphaned because they were replaced by new objects, and the parent reference was updated to point to the new object.

Comment: It's often quicker to create a new table, retaining only the desired rows.

Comment: Are you talking about `FOREIGN KEYS`?  If so say so.  "Orphaned" and "class" and "objects" are not database terms.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for any future finders. After doing some research I found this to be about as ideal a solution I could put together.

Step 1: Create a new temporary table with the exact same structure as the one we're trying to trim down in size.

Step 2: Identify tables/columns that reference the class in question (X).

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_schema = 'my_db_name' 
AND column_name LIKE '%reference_column%'
```

Step 3: For each row in those tables/columns with a non-null reference, get the row of X that they reference and copy it to the new table, if it doesn't already exist in the new table. I did this table by table, and used a chunked approach of 1000 records at a time to save system memory. I wrote this logic in my application layer to better control it. I used `INSERT IGNORE` to avoid creating primary key conflicts since some of the references were to the same X object.

Step 4: Delete the old table, rename the new one to the same name as the old one.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE old_table; 
RENAME TABLE new_table TO old_table;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

All told this takes about an hour to run in my environment where table X has ~7 million rows and I have ~10 other tables making reference to it.